How can I format a column so all dates are reflecting as mm-dd-yyyy in excel?
Apologies if this is redundant, I searched around for an answer on this but I just was having continued difficulty. Currently, I have open an excel spreadsheet, and am looking at a column that is giving me dates. However, there are two formats. The format MM/DD/YYYY and DD-MM-YYYY. However, when I highlight the entire column and select date, only the mm/dd/YYYY seem to change if I choose short or long term date. The dates in the dd-mm-YYYY do not respond no matter what. So far, I have attempted to click "data" and have tried text to columns, and that does not work. I have also tried replacing "-" with "/" but that won't work either, and would still leave me the problem of the format being dd/mm/YYYY which is also incorrect still. For whatever reason, excel just does not recognize the dates in the dd-mm-YYYY and I am clueless as to why that is. Again, ultimately I just want all dates to be recognized and also in MM/DD/YYYY format.


The dd-mm-YYYY dates are clearly entered as text. You need to parse those to get them to be dates and not text.

What's the source of these date values? Usually the best option is to clean the source data and stop you needing to write a horrible formula that does the job for you or to need to repeatedly clean your data (which is easy to do, but mind numbingly boring).

Thank you so much for your input! The source is from sample data in a project I am working on. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nVYJrAVvUegJjX9vChxWCW61TzBQ49td the file is the financial_loan.csv. Apologies I am a novice, how would one go about isolating the dates that are text, and convert to date?

I should have noticed it before. The dates that have remained strings are ones that Excel can't parse as a valid date. Your computer is set to recognize US date format, so when it encounters a date where the first value is greater than 12 (i.e. it thinks the month value is 13 or above) then it fails and leaves it as text.

@sullivan11342 Try this formula =IF(ISNUMBER(I2),I2,DATE(RIGHT(I2,4),MID(I2,4,2),LEFT(I2,2))) and let me know your feedback please.

@Harun24hr - No, the OP is importing dd-MM-yyyy dates on to a PC that is expecting MM/dd/yyyy format. It's failing to import dates where it thinks the month is greater than 12. That means the dates that are being imported are swapping the month and day around. It's creating invalid data.

@Enigmativity Then we have to apply both for date data to swap day to month and month to date. And Text data dd-MMM-yyyy to date. I have applied just for one type.

Give a try to =IF(ISNUMBER(I2),DATE(YEAR(I2),DAY(I2),MONTH(I2)),DATE(RIGHT(I2,4),MID(I2,4,2),LEFT(I2,2))).

@nkalvi You didn't realize that Excel has switched the days and months and created wrong dates. Observe Harun24hr's formula more closely and realize how the following handles this issue: DATE(YEAR(I2),DAY(I2),MONTH(I2)) i.e. see how the day is read from the month and month from the day. In your current formula, the valid (wrong) dates are left as they are.

@nkalvi - The OP's computer is parsing 12-01-2024 as MM-DD-YYYY when it should be parsed as DD-MM-YYYY. The OP's Excel thinks that the date is December 1, 2024 when in fact it is January 12, 2024, hence why the swap is needed.

Just as a handy hint for future readers - use ISO 8601 format - yyyy-MM-dd - then there is no confusion and hours of time can be saved.

@VBasic2008 & Enigmativity, thanks for kindly explaining. I have finally understood that they were not entered as mm/dd/yyyy but as dd-mm-yyyy and since they were 'valid' when interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy Excel converted those accordingly. I'll update my answer.

@nkalvi - The @ notifications only work for one person at a time. If you want to notify two people you need two comments.

Thank you @Enigmativity, I'm aware of it. Again, I appreciate you taking time to explain the issue. I wish it would be possible in the future.

Update 2024-09-24
I finally understood that Excel had converted some dates in dd-mm-yyyy format since they were 'valid' when interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy ('invalid' ones were left as dd-mm-yyyy.) Those 'valid' ones also need conversion.
Enigmativity and VBasic2008 kindly helped me to grasp it.

Here's a way to do it (Excel 2021 and later):

In a separate column enter following formula, replacing A1:A21 with the correct range from your data

=LET(
    dates, A2:A34,
    IF(
        ISNUMBER(dates),
        DATE(YEAR(dates), DAY(dates), MONTH(dates)),
        DATE(RIGHT(dates, 4), MID(dates, 4, 2), LEFT(dates, 2))
    )
)


If you need to original values changed:

Copy the result
Paste over the original column as values (Edit > Paste Special... > Values)


Otherwise use the values from this new column in calculations



Excel - Import CSV
Alternatively, in Excel when

importing via File > Import > CSV
or, converting via Data > Text to Columns

select the appropriate option for date columns:


Nice addition of using the Text Import Wizard. I opted for the VBA's Workbook.OpenText method using the same DMY (4) for columns 8, 9, 10, and 12 but couldn't get it to work.

The text import wizard imported it correctly (as far as I can 'see' :) Thanks again for helping me today.

The dates that have remained strings are ones that Excel can't parse as a valid date. Your computer is set to recognize US date format, so when it encounters a date where the first value is greater than 12 (i.e. it thinks the month value is 13 or above) then it fails and leaves it as text.
And, because of that, it's swapping the month and day for dates that it thinks it can parse.
So 06-09-2024 is parsed as 2024-06-09 when it should be 2024-09-06. You're corrupting your own data. Simply fixing the "text" dates is not sufficient.
Instead of opening the CSV directly, go to the Data tab and select From Text/CSV.
That's bring you to the Power Query editor where you can load the CSV and tell the editor what format your fields are.
It'll then import all of the dates correctly.

Handle International Dates Issue Using Power Query or Excel Formula
Using Excel Formulas (Manual Steps)
Single Cell (Any Version)
    =IF(ISTEXT(I2),
        DATE(RIGHT(I2,4),MID(I2,4,2),LEFT(I2,2)),
        DATE(YEAR(I2),DAY(I2),MONTH(I2))))

Sngle Columm (MS365, Excel 2021)
   =LET(I2:I38577,
       IF(ISTEXT(data),
           DATE(RIGHT(data,4),MID(data,4,2),LEFT(data,2)),
           DATE(YEAR(data),DAY(data),MONTH(data))))

Excel 2021
   =LET(data,INDEX(A2:X38577,,{8,9,10,12}),
       IF(ISTEXT(data),
           DATE(RIGHT(data,4),MID(data,4,2),LEFT(data,2)),
           DATE(YEAR(data),DAY(data),MONTH(data))))

MS365
   =LET(data,CHOOSECOLS(A2:X38577,8,9,10,12),
       IF(ISTEXT(data),
           DATE(RIGHT(data,4),MID(data,4,2),LEFT(data,2)),
           DATE(YEAR(data),DAY(data),MONTH(data))))

Using Power Query (Automatic (Recommended))

let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("E:\Downloads\financial_loan.csv"),
       [Delimiter=",", Columns=24, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers", 
        {{"issue_date", type date}, {"last_credit_pull_date", type date}, 
        {"last_payment_date", type date}, {"next_payment_date", type date}}, "de-DE"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type with Locale",
        {{"id", Int64.Type}, {"member_id", Int64.Type}, {"total_acc", Int64.Type}, 
        {"annual_income", Currency.Type}, {"installment", Currency.Type}, 
        {"loan_amount", Currency.Type}, {"total_payment", Currency.Type}, 
        {"int_rate", Percentage.Type}, {"dti", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"


In Excel, use the desired or open a new workbook. Then select...
Ribbon-->Data-->Get & Transform Data-->Get Data-->Launch Power Query Editor...

to open Power Query Editor.

In Power Query Editor, select...
Ribbon-->New Query-->New Source-->Other Sources-->Blank Query

to add a new blank query.

In Power Query Editor, select...
Ribbon-->Query-->Advanded Editor

to open Advanced Editor.

In Advanced Editor, replace the template code with the one above. Replace "E:\Downloads\financial_loan.csv" with your actual file path. Select Done.

Observe the imported data for a while. This is the moment where you could easily add more changes.




In Power Query Editor, select...
Ribbon-->Close-->Close & Load To...

to close Power Query and open Excel's Import Data dialog.

In the Import Data dialog, select the Table radio button (if not already) and below the label Where do you want to put the data?, either navigate to a cell in an existing worksheet or select a new worksheet and at the bottom press OK.




Check the cells with the dates indented to the left: these are likely not set as date type but are formatted as text, which is why they are not affected by the change.
Try selecting the column, go to 'Cells properties', choose the 'Custom' format type, and enter the desired format in the 'Type' box as the follow:
dd-mm-yyyy

After that you will be able to implement any conversion on cells.

That would just format the correct dates to look like the incorrect ones.

yes, but the problem is that column contains mixed type of data (string and date). So, first of all, he should homogenize cells contents before implement any solution to obtain the final result

No, that's precisely what not to do. It would make some of the dates have flipped months and days and others not.

i apologize but i haden't understood

What haven't you understood?
